# Cannot Find Browsing history in IOS7

Tags: safari, ios, history

On previous versions of iOS, I knew how to get a list of sites previously visited.   I need to get URL of site i browsed about 3 weeks ago.

Anybody know if this is missing form IOS7 or if it is hidden in the user interface somewhere.   For the record I do not have "Do Not Track" enabled, but that should not make a difference as that is request to servers not internal Safari setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                             Click the bookmarks Button:
```

[image]

---

```
               You will then need to click the Parent Folder button:
```

---

[image]

---

```
             Until you come to the beginning of the Bookmarks list.
```

---

[image]

```
               There you should see the history.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your browser is black (top background) you are browsing in Private.

Open a new browser tab and in the lower left tap PRIVATE to turn it off. The background will become white and history will be tracked again.

Comment: you saved my day Marc.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a new blank page in Safari (iOS 7.0.3), the second icon on the right in the bottom of the screen will bring you a menu. The second item in the menu is "History".

Answer (score -3):

I think this is a problem with IOS 7. My history doesn't have any records. Tried many different settings.

Comment: Mark Hunter's answer explains how to find is. The feature is still there, but the interface has changed substantially.